# Syntax error when trying to insert from a mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger to insert into a new table using values from two different tables (I'm using MySQL 5.5.27).

I get a syntax error when I try this but cannot see where the error is.

```
    DECLARE _Token VARCHAR(255);
SELECT token INTO _Token FROM appusers ON username = NEW.username;
INSERT INTO queue (token, message) VALUES (_Token, NEW.milestone);
```

My assumption is that it doesn't like the DECLARE because when I use the following I get message that _Token is an undeclared variable.

```
  SELECT token INTO _Token FROM appusers ON username = NEW.username;
INSERT INTO queue (token, message) VALUES (_Token, NEW.milestone);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try do it with a single insert statement

```
INSERT INTO queue (token, message)
SELECT token, NEW.milestone
  FROM appusers 
 WHERE username = NEW.username;
```